# Get date from postgres as stated in database (without timezone offset)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgresql with a column named 'date_of_birth' as a date field.

In this, I have a value: '2000-01-01'.

The problem is, I don't get the correct value from it.

If I do this: `SELECT date_of_birth FROM users`, I get this result:

```
1999-12-31T23:00:00.000Z
```

I'm in timezone UTC+1. Timezone of the db is UTC (`SHOW TIMEZONE`).

I just need as a result: '2000-01-01'. NOT with the time zone.

Using `SELECT date_of_birth::date FROM users` gives me the same result.

Comment: IS Using SELECT date_of_birth::date FROM users does not giove you 1999-12-31??

Comment: If `date_of_birth` is indeed a `date` column, then the output you see is applied by your SQL client. Postgres does not contain a time or even time zone information in a `date` column. Which tool do you use to query the database - you need to check with _that_.

Comment: Please paste the snippet of Users table description. As in some of my table there is a start date like this `start_date            | date                     |           |          |` having a date field and stores the information of `2022-01-10` format. If I query it gives me in the same format.